# Nextjs router push taking a few seconds to update after redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I have a form in my NextJS app that uses `react-hook-form` to save some data to the DB via an API, and then it redirects the user back to the listing page ... The problem I am seeing is when the user is redirected back to the listing page, it takes about 3 seconds to actually refresh and see the new entry ... I have a page loader that shows a spinner while fetching the data on the listing page, but it doesn't seem to work when creating a new entry.

On my form, I'm saving and redirecting using the following;

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    setLoading(true)

    try {
        await axios.post('/api/jobs', data)

        router.push('/jobs')
    } catch (error) {
        setShowErrors(error.response.data.errors)
    } finally {
        setLoading(false)
    }
})
```

And in the jobs listing page, I am getting the data using the following;

```
const { data: jobsdata, error } = useSWR('/api/jobs', () => 
    axios.get('/api/jobs')
        .then(response => response.data.data)
)

if (! jobsdata) {
    return (<PageLoader />)
}
```

Is there a way to refresh the data before being shown on the jobs listing page so that the 3+ second delay doesn't happen and the data is there when the user is redirected?

Comment: I have read this post several times. But I can't understand what's the main issue. Can you add more details or clarity to make it a little bit more focused? What's the exact issue? I mean, What is your expectation that doesn't happen?

Comment: are you using page directory or app directory??
did you notice this in dev env or prod as well?? Sometimes dev enviroment is a bit slower

Comment: Below part is from job listing page I assume. Is this component has any hooks to refresh data, because when you push listing page you are returning to already created component. If state hasn't been changed, it won't rerender

Comment: Please provide a minimal runnable demo on `codepen` or `codesandbox`, which is better for debugging. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because of  Stale-While-Revalidate. This serves stale data and then revalidates it in the background. And when you navigate back to the listing page SWR is serving stale data before it has a chance to revalidate.

I would trigger revalidation manually when navigating back to listing page using `mutate`.

```
import { mutate } from "swr";

const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
        await axios.post('/api/jobs', data);

        // Trigger revalidation (or "refetch") to make sure data is correct
        mutate('/api/jobs');

        router.push('/jobs');
    } catch (error) {
        setShowErrors(error.response.data.errors);
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
});
```

Edit:
If solution above didnt help much with delay, you can try optimistically update the UI as if new data was already there and then revalidate in the background.

```
    const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);

    // Optimistically update cache with new data
    const newJob = { 
    // your new job data structure here, like: 
    id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9), // temporary ID, replace with real ID when API returns it
    title: data.title,
    description: data.description
    // ... any other fields
    };

    mutate('/api/jobs', [...jobsdata, newJob], false);

    try {
        await axios.post('/api/jobs', data);

        // Trigger revalidation (or "refetch") to make sure data is correct
        mutate('/api/jobs');

        router.push('/jobs');
    } catch (error) {
        // On error, rollback to the previous value
        mutate('/api/jobs', jobsdata, false);
        setShowErrors(error.response.data.errors);
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work either :( .. Still the few seconds wait on the listing page

Comment: I have another idea using Optimistic UI. Give me some time and I will explain

Comment: I am getting a `ReferenceError: jobsdata is not defined` ... But is that because they are on different pages? the jobsdata is on the index page and this code is on the create page

Answer (score 0):

After successfully posting the new entry in your form, you can manually update the SWR cache with the new data using the mutate function provided by SWR. This way, the data will be instantly available when the user is redirected.
Here's how you can modify your onSubmit function:

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    setLoading(true)

    try {
        // Post the new entry
        await axios.post('/api/jobs', data)

        // Manually update the SWR cache for the jobs data
        mutate('/api/jobs') // This will trigger a re-fetch of the data
        router.push('/jobs')
    } catch (error) {
        setShowErrors(error.response.data.errors)
    } finally {
        setLoading(false)
    }
})
```

By calling mutate('/api/jobs'), you tell SWR to re-fetch the data immediately. This way, when the user is redirected to the jobs listing page, the updated data should be available without the delay.

Make sure you have imported the mutate function from the SWR library:

```
import useSWR, { mutate } from 'swr';
```